# Substituting a variable in the ODE: $ky''+cy'+y(1-y)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $k,c$ be constants. I would like to use a new variable $z=y'$ to make the following ODE into a first order ODE :

$ky''+cy'+y(1-y)=0$

I don't see how to handle the $y(1-y)$ term...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot do it. Anyway, $y=0$ and $y=1$ are two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrarily to what one could say at first sight, Maple yields the answer in the form requested by the OP. One has to set $z=y(x)$ and this gives the equation
$$
w(z)\frac{dw(z)}{dz}+\frac{1}{k}\left(c\cdot w(z)-z^2+z\right)=0
$$
and
$$
x=\int\frac{dz}{w(z)}+C,
$$
where $C$ is an integration constant and finally
$$
w(z)=\frac{dy}{dx}.
$$

Comment: The trouble is that $w(z)\frac{dw(z)}{dz}+\frac{1}{k}\left(c\cdot w(z)-z^2+z\right)=0$ is an Abel equation of the second kind. The most likely, there is no close form for $w(z)$. So the integral $\int\frac{dz}{w(z)}$ is purely formal and of no use.

Comment: @JJacquelin I agree but it is interesting to see the reduction to a first order ode anyway.

Comment: @Jin : Yes, you are right. As well, in my answer there is no result in closed form.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform it to a first order system by letting $z_1(x)=y(x)$ and $z_2(x) = y'(x)$. Then you will get with $z(x)=\begin{bmatrix}z_1(x)\\z_2(x)\end{bmatrix}$:

\begin{align*}
z'(x) &= \begin{bmatrix}z_1'(x)\\z_2'(x)\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}y'(x)\\y''(x)\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}y'(x)\\-\frac{c}k y'(x) - \frac1k y(x)\bigl(1-y(x)\bigr)\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}z_2(x)\\-\frac{c}k z_2(x) - \frac1k z_1(x)\bigl(1-z_1(x)\bigr)\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$k\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+c\frac{dy}{dx}+y(1-y)=0 \tag 1$$

This equation is on autonomous kind. The usual change in the aim to reduce the order from 2 to 1 is :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=F(y)$$
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dF(y)}{dx}=\frac{dF}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=F(y)\frac{dF}{dy}$
$$kF(y)\frac{dF}{dy}+cF(y)+y(1-y)=0$$
$$F(y)\frac{dF}{dy}=-\frac{c}{k}F(y)+\frac{1}{k}y(y-1)$$
Let $F(y)=\frac{1}{G(y)}$
$$\frac{dG}{dy}=-\frac{c}{k}G^2+\frac{1}{k}y(1-y)G^3$$
This is an Abel's differential equation of the first kind.

In the general case there is no closed form for the solutions. In practice, better use numerical method to directly solve Eq.$(1)$.

Note that obvious particular solutions of Eq.$(1)$ are $y(x)=0$ and $y(x)=1$. Of course, this is not the general solution.